# integral in the question Sign of remainder in series for $cos$ and $sin$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I don't know Why does the second equal sign in these two equations hold true. I tried integration by parts but couldn't cancel it out.

[Sign of remainder in series for $\cos$ and $\sin$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477437/sign-of-remainder-in-series-for-cos-and-sin)

$$\begin{align}
\cos y &= \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}y^{2k} + \frac{1}{(2m)!}\int_0^y (y-t)^{2m} \cos^{(2m+1)}t\,dt\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}y^{2k} + \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{(2m)!} \int_0^y (y-t)^{2m} \sin t\,dt,
\end{align}$$

for $\sin$ we choose $n = 2m-1$ and obtain

$$\begin{align}
\sin y &= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}y^{2k+1} + \frac{1}{(2m-1)!}\int_0^y (y-t)^{2m-1} \sin^{2m} t\,dt\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}y^{2k+1} + \frac{(-1)^m}{(2m-1)!} \int_0^y (y-t)^{2m-1}\sin t\, dt.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for integration by parts. The integrals are equal because $(\sin t)'' = -\sin t$, so that
$$
  \sin^{(2m)} t = (-1)^{m} \sin t
$$
and
$$
 \cos^{(2m+1)} t = - \sin^{(2m)} t = (-1)^{m+1} \sin t \, .
$$