# integral inequality in the question Sign of remainder in series for $\cos$ and $\sin$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

in the solution of [Sign of remainder in series for $\cos$ and $\sin$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477437/sign-of-remainder-in-series-for-cos-and-sin)
it says So it remains to see that

$$\int_0^y (y-t)^k \sin t\, dt > 0$$

for all $y > 0$ and $k > 0$. But that follows since $(y-t)^k$ is a strictly decreasing positive function, so while $2\pi m \leqslant y$ we have

$$\int_{2(m-1)\pi}^{(2m-1)\pi} (y-t)^k\sin t\,dt > (y-(2m-1)\pi)^k\int_0^\pi\sin t\,dt > \int_{(2m-1)\pi}^{2m\pi}(y-t)^k \lvert \sin t\rvert\,dt,$$

my question is: In this solution, why does the second inequality hold? I tried integrating the equation $$\int_{(2m-1)\pi}^{2m\pi}(y-t)^k dt=\frac{-(y-2m\pi)^{k+1}+(y-(2m-1)\pi)^{k+1}}{k+1}
$$ but couldn't see the connection with this inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function  $(y-t)^k$ is strictly monotonically decreasing, we only need to substitute $(2m-1)\pi$ in the values of t on the left and right sides of the inequality to obtain the conclusion required by the inequality.

As for the absolute value of sin(t), it can be obtained from the following discussion.The equal sign is because m is an integer, and sin(t) is always positive in the interval, so adding the absolute value does not affect the inequality.
$$ (y-(2m-1)\pi)^k\int_0^\pi\sin t\,dt >\int_{(2m-1)\pi}^{2m\pi}(y-t)^k \sin tdt= \int_{(2m-1)\pi}^{2m\pi}(y-t)^k \lvert \sin t\rvert\,dt$$